# Mimicking VBA Input ListControl in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, shinywidgets

Is it possible to generate VBA List Control input (as shown in the screenshot) in an R Shiny dashboard?

[VBA List Input Example Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSvUP.png)

Comment: Your also may want to check out the shinyWidgets package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.5.2  http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/

Comment: Thanks alot. That is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to mimic that. A `selectInput` can do that when you set the `size` argument to a value larger than 1. Check the documentation to see how `size` works (it has limitations).